# how to well deserialize data in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

i have data from a webservice in json format and i would like to set json data to an object, but when i print this in command line i get the response `Instance of User`, here is what i did :

```
class User {
  static bool isSuccessful = false;
  static bool isSuccessful2 = false;
  String platform = "MOBILE";
  String code;
  static String lastUsedEmail = '';
  int userId = 0;
  String firstName = '';
  int accountTypeId = 1;
  String lastName = '';
  String email = '';
  String link = "";
  String country = "";
  String countryName = "";
  String pin = "";
  String cni = '';
  String currency = "";
  String msisdn = '';
  String password = '';
  String raisonSocial = '';
  String address = '';
  String secondaryAddress = '';
  String nickName = '';
  String profil = 'User';
  List<prefix.Transaction> transactions = [];
  List<dynamic> accounts = [];
  String userAccount;
  Account account;

  User.full(
      this.userId,
      this.firstName,
      this.lastName,
      this.email,
      this.link,
      this.country,
      this.cni,
      this.msisdn,
      this.password,
      this.raisonSocial,
      this.address,
      this.secondaryAddress,
      this.nickName,
      this.profil,
      this.currency,
      this.userAccount,
      this.platform,
      this.countryName);

  User();

  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    User user;

    if (json['user'] is Map) {
      user = User.full(
          json['user']['userId'],
          json['user']['firstName'],
          json['user']['lastName'],
          json['user']['email'],
          json['user']['link'],
          json['user']['country'],
          json['user']['cni'],
          json['user']['msisdn'],
          json['user']['password'],
          json['user']['raisonSocial'],
          json['user']['address'],
          json['user']['secondaryAddress'],
          json['user']['nickName'],
          json['user']['profil'],
          json['user']['nickName'],
          json['user']['currency'],
          json['user']['platform'],
          json['user']['pays']);
    } else {
      user = User();
    }

    Account account = Account.fromJson(json);
    user.account = account;
    return user;
  }
}
```

and when i return the response like `return User.fromJson(json.decode(userData));`
i get `instance of User`. the `userData` variable is data from web service i have store with `SharePreferences package` in local storage as a String and i verified this variable is not null.

Comment: I'd say "instance of User" is pretty much there.  Then you can access the member variables like lastName and email and so on.  What's your actual question?

Comment: when i instance a user like this `User usr = await User.loadUserDataFromStorage()` `  static Future<User> loadUserDataFromStorage() async {
    String userData = await RestClient.getStringFromStorage('user');
    if (userData == '') {
      return User();
    } else {
      return User.fromJson(json.decode(userData));
    }
  }`  i print `usr` value but i got the `instance of User` response

Comment: try 

print(usr.firstName);